# Error 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, oledb

I have an application developed in C# (WebForms .net 4.5.1) where we import some spreadsheets.

If I open my application now and import some spreadsheet, the import will be successful, but after a while this import starts to thrown an error out of nowhere and the error below appears:

```
2022-02-22 20:33:12,842 [476] ERROR The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
2022-02-22 20:33:12,904 [476] at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
```

So, we have to restart the IIS and the import works normally again, even if we import the same worksheet that threw an error before.

It is running on a Windows Server 2016 built on 32bit.

Locally it never happens.

Comment: Instead of using the JET driver use ExcelDataReader or another package that can read Excel files natively.

Comment: BTW .NET Framework 4.5.1 reached End-Of-Life *several* years ago. Even [4.5.2-4.6.1 will reach End-Of-Life on April 2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/). That's 1 month away. That's not just out-of-support, that means *no* support at all, even for security issues.

Comment: In fact,  you're already running on 4.6.2 .NET 4.x runtimes are binary replacements which means installing a newer one replaces the older one. Windows Server 2016 [comes with 4.6.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#net-framework-462) and can't be downgraded.